# Why updating of dependencies in composer is so slow?

Tags: symfony, dependencies, composer-php

I am using composer (http://getcomposer.org/) to manage installed bundles in the `Symfony2` (symfony v 2.1.3). Version of the composer is `de3188c`.

I have problem that when I add new bundle into the composer.json and execute it the time to show messages about Updating dependencies and next downloading them all is very low.

I have this data in the composer.json (see below) and the executing time is approximately 20 MINUTES!!! The internet connection is fast enough I can download big files very fast...

Is there any trick to make it faster?

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "webignition/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web"
}
```

Comment: What you can do - is to specify needed tag (instead of 2.1.* use 2.1.1 f.e.)

Comment: In Early December 2014, an optimisation was found that stopped trying to garbage-collect memory during a Composer run. Because of some very specific things what were being done within Composer, it took a long time, but ultimately did very little. After the patch, many report that Composer will take more memory, but run in half, or even less time.

Comment: Also try updating composer.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try to specify a version for each dependency in composer.json and use the option `--prefer-dist` when calling composer. It will download ZIP files from the repositories (if available) instead of the single files.

```
php composer.phar install --prefer-dist
```

Comment: It improves significantly the load time for my very simple project which has a lot of transitive dependancies (using phpunit)

Comment: it also keeps a copy of the sit in ~/.composer so other projects, or updates etc will go there first.

Comment: Seemed to be my problem exactly. When i just ran composer install without the lock-file it took like 30 minutes .. When i used the lock-file it was finished within seconds.

Answer (score 23):

Since you accepted an answer, it looks like that solved your problem. Just in case anybody else stumbles across this question though (like I did when I was searching), in my case, a really slow Composer install had to do with my PHP version (word of warning, I am a complete and utter Composer newbie), even though Composer ran through its standard checks and said everything was fine. I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and was too lazy to upgrade from the default PHP 5.3.10 (the same version you're running) in the Precise repo.

Installing Twig via Composer originally took me around 30 minutes. I gave up installing Doctrine after it took more than an hour. I upgraded to 5.4.17 (using this PPA https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) and installing Doctrine was done in a matter of seconds.

Comment: +1 regardless of PHP upgrade not being an option, because the accepted answer didn't work for me neither.

Comment: Works a lot faster in PHP 5.5.9 as well. I have heard people having amazing results using composer on HHVM too.

Comment: Also disabling xdebug seems to help.

Answer (score 15):

I have found that it is also very slow, in the tens of minutes slow.

For me I added `-vvv` and found it was hanging at stuff like 
`Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-active$53cdf887c8d2925b3501f47d6980fb7bda2310716369bf7a84857c6e62bbab0f.json`

I then went to the browser and tried to download that JSON file and sure enough. It was packagist.org to be the cause of the slowness.

Comment: This is the root cause of slowness in my case.

Comment: This seemed to work for me (Not entirely but at least it's one thing less) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30716919/775941

Answer (score 15):

In my case, the above suggestions didn't make a difference. What did was to use the `HTTPS` protocol for `packagist`:

```
php composer.phar config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

or

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

depending on your setup

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Would personally have marked this as the best answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me

Comment: I've tried many solutions (like disable xdebug, activate cache, adding --prefer-dist)
none of that works, by chance I've come on this answer, And it was the only solution who really solve the issue. Should be marked as best answer for my case.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose this use I used the **require** command with **-vvv** attribute.

```
composer require larapack/dd -vvv
```

In my case I've found that the slow speed of composer was because of fxp/composer-asset-plugin.

```
composer global show
composer global remove fxp/composer-asset-plugin
```

and voila