# Why is PHP Composer so slow?

Tags: php, composer-php

Why is [PHP Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software)) so slow when all I do is init a project with zero dependencies? Here are the commands I run:

```
composer init
```

<step through composer.json creation, define 0 zero dependencies>

```
composer install
```

Wait 3 minutes (not an exaggeration).

All composer has to do is pull in an autoloader and create `/vendor`, so why does it take so long? For that matter, why doesn't that step happen on `composer init`?

Is there a configuration option I can use to pull in a cached autloader and vendor upon `init`?

Comment: More seriously: have you updated your composer in the last 30 days? There was a major performance improvement to the code just last month

Comment: I started `compose install` more than 5 minutes ago and it didn't complete yet. `Composer version 1.0-dev (07c644ac229a21df80180598d8bb9aaba232eecb) 2015-02-03 12:51:10`. Maybe it's not the most recent version but still newer than your IBM mainframe ;-)

Comment: Please confirm you've done `composer self-update`

Comment: I have, updated it last week or so.

Comment: I struggled with composer update and composer self-update being incredibly slow. Taking more than 15 minutes and then throwing exceptions. I changed my router DNS servers (from Google's to my ISP's own) and composer worked like a charm.

Comment: I was using my ISPs DNS servers, but based on the above comment, I put packagist.org in my /etc/hosts file and things started working. Note you shouldn't consider this canonical as packagist.org's IP is subject to change at any moment. However, it got me through an initial installation.

Comment: now, on my machine even `composer --version` is slow (otherwise a fast machine - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 16GB DDR3, SSD)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Also, disable [Xdebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug). Xdebug can cause Composer to take minutes even when running a command as simple as `composer --version`.

Comment: This actually turned out to be my issue. Xdebug makes composer run ultra slow.

Comment: In the time of writing, I had the same performance with or without debug, since in 2020/2019 composer automatically disabled xdebug when running, in spite of that installing yii2-starter-kit took about 200 seconds with all libraries be it w/wo xdebug, so this reply is becoming outdated

Comment: Saw this, pulled up my debugger. Found that even though xdebug is configured for FPM only, the CLI had initiated it and my IDE was sitting  there at a break point waiting for me. Hit continue and composer kicked right back in.

Answer (score 393):

Because Composer is implemented by `file_get_contents()`. That has no TCP optimizations, no Keep-Alive, no multiplexing, etc.

I created a Composer plugin to download packages in parallel: https://packagist.org/packages/hirak/prestissimo

```
$ composer global require hirak/prestissimo
```

Please try it. In my environment, `composer install` becomes 10 times faster.

Comment: Good news: This was apparently merged into Composer 2 in January 2019: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/7904

Comment: @ChuckLeButt but release still out of sight :(

Answer (score 66):

1. Make sure you have the latest version of Composer.
2. Install in verbose mode by adding -vvv, for example `composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*" -vvv`
3. If you are able to find out where Composer is facing slowness, for example mine was getting stuck for 5 minutes when downloading packages. It took >5 minutes to download a 20 kB file on a 50 Mbit/s connection. This was because it was downloading the packages from packagist using HTTP and not HTTPS. Making these changes to the configuration has resolved my issue: 
   `composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

Comment: I'm new to composer and try to fix this for 2 days, after read your comment and add -vvv, it's finally worked. 1000 upvotes

Comment: #3 solved it for me. You are my hero right now. Was worried for quite some time now why it is so slow and only worked on some internet connections. Thx!

Comment: `composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org ` what was that! Awesome! 

Answer (score 13):

The same here. Get more details with "composer install --profile -vvv". In my case it takes a long time to download a few JSON files. They get cached on my server, but they are still downloaded with every Composer update/install call.

... 30 minutes later ...

It looks like some performance problem @packagist.org. Now the Composer install runs within 2 seconds! And downloaded JSON files are properly cached.

Comment: "They get cached on my server but are still downloaded with every composer update/install call" THIS !! Have you found a solution for this problem ? I have a slow connection and it's terrible to see that.

Answer (score 10):

I was running into this issue, and it was throwing me for a curve since I don't have Xdebug installed anywhere on my machine. It turns out that it was [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addressing mode failures. So to test I ran

```
curl --ipv4 'https://packagist.org/packages.json'
curl --ipv6 'https://packagist.org/packages.json'
```

IPv4 went through, but IPv6 failed. In the end, you should look to find out why you're networking stack doesn't support it, but in my case, I decided to just give preference to IPv4 traffic until I can resolve that. On [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) I created/modified the file /etc/gai.conf and put in the following:

```
label       ::1/128        0
label       ::/0           1
label       2002::/16      2
label       ::/96          3
label       ::ffff:0:0/96  4
precedence  ::1/128        50
precedence  ::/0           40
precedence  2002::/16      30
precedence  ::/96          20
precedence  ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

On Ubuntu you can also edit that file and uncomment the line

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

[Source on Rackspace Community Hub](https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/public-cloud-forum/5110/how-to-prefer-ipv4-over-ipv6-in-ubuntu-and-centos)

Comment: Just for a note, this did not seem to help me personally, although I will have to resimulate it to confirm all the options, which of them could be the cause.

Comment: @FentomX1 Sorry to hear that. That's why I included the test up top. If you do both curl tests and it's connecting, then obviously, the changes shouldn't be made because your network is set up correctly.

Comment: Found a short YouTube video showing how to do this on Windows 10. It fixed my problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63Lt_vlNWLc

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 VPS, you need to do the following:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
composer global require hirak/prestissimo
```

It configures IPv4 as preferred over IPv6.

https://serverfault.com/questions/93717/setting-ipv4-as-preferred-protocol-over-ipv6

Comment: since i installed prestissimo, my composer speed has been excellent.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works even for ubuntu 18.04LTS

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What does that first line do?

Comment: @NicoHaase If you look at the timestamps, this answer is actually a response to the issue I described, but they didn't put it as a comment. I incorporated it into my answer anyways. It seems that packagist prefers to use IPV6, but some networks still don't work well with it. The first line makes it so that your Linux Machine will prefer IPv4 addresses and look for those first.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Conclusion: no solution listed here or generally seems to be bulletproof.
What ultimately helps is usually using composer incrementally, requiring or removing only a single package at a time using `composer require`, `composer remove` command,  also regards adding any "non-dependency specific" setting, any library can be added/removed for the sake of it of updating/refreshing the composer.json lock cache configuration.

Grouping my experience with answers from here and from the linked in question.

Prior I tried every single solution mention in this question to this time. However, it still did not help me, though I tried/noticed installing any other single library was considerably fast, so I went on investigating libraries one by one which could cause the bottle-neck.

**1) YES** And I located it to be codeception, `"codeception/codeception": "2.4.0",`

It took almost 200 seconds alone, though running it together with other libraries seemed at some times running almost for 12 minutes. Furthermore composer does not seem to reflect real-time when after initiating for 20 seconds it outputs it run 0.35s and so on later.

```
[374.9MiB/173.14s]     39/45:   https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template/legacy.zip/31f8b717e51d9a2afca6c9f046f5d69fc27c8686
[374.9MiB/173.16s]     40/45:   https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/diff/legacy.zip/720fcc7e9b5cf384ea68d9d930d480907a0c1a29
[374.9MiB/173.17s]     41/45:   https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/exporter/legacy.zip/68609e1261d215ea5b21b7987539cbfbe156ec3e
[374.9MiB/173.19s]     42/45:   https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/legacy.zip/f9756fd4f43f014cb2dca98deeaaa8ce5500a36e
[374.9MiB/173.20s]     43/45:   https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/recursion-context/legacy.zip/5b0cd723502bac3b006cbf3dbf7a1e3fcefe4fa8
[374.9MiB/173.23s]     44/45:   https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/legacy.zip/4cab20a326d14de7575a8e235c70d879b569a57a
[374.9MiB/173.24s]     45/45:   https://codeload.github.com/doctrine/instantiator/legacy.zip/ae466f726242e637cebdd526a7d991b9433bacf1
[374.9MiB/173.24s]     Finished: success: 45, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 45
[374.8MiB/173.25s] Analyzed 6622 packages to resolve dependencies
[374.8MiB/173.25s] Analyzed 435842 rules to resolve dependencies
[374.8MiB/173.25s] Package operations: 54 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
[374.8MiB/173.26s] Installs: sebastian/recursion-context:3.0.0, sebastian/exporter:3.1.2, doctrine/instantiator:1.3.0, phpunit/php-text-template:1.2.1, phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:6.1.2, codeception/stub:1.0.4, sebastian/diff:3.0.2, sebastian/comparator:3.0.2, theseer/tokenizer:1.1.3, sebastian/version:2.0.1, sebastian/environment:3.1.0, sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup:1.0.1, phpunit/php-token-stream:3.1.1, phpunit/php-file-iterator:1.4.5, phpunit/php-code-coverage:6.0.5, sebastian/object-reflector:1.1.1, sebastian/object-enumerator:3.0.3, sebastian/global-state:2.0.0, phpunit/php-timer:2.1.2, symfony/polyfill-ctype:v1.17.0, webmozart/assert:1.8.0, phpdocumentor/reflection-common:2.1.0, phpdocumentor/type-resolver:1.1.0, phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock:5.1.0, phpspec/prophecy:v1.10.3, myclabs/deep-copy:1.9.5, sebastian/resource-operations:1.0.0, phar-io/version:1.0.1, phar-io/manifest:1.0.1, phpunit/phpunit:7.1.5, codeception/phpunit-wrapper:7.6.1, symfony/yaml:v4.4.8, behat/gherkin:v4.6.2, symfony/polyfill-mbstring:v1.17.0, symfony/dom-crawler:v4.4.8, symfony/css-selector:v4.4.8, symfony/browser-kit:v4.4.8, symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts:v1.1.7, psr/container:1.0.0, symfony/event-dispatcher:v4.4.8, symfony/service-contracts:v2.0.1, symfony/polyfill-php73:v1.17.0, symfony/console:v4.4.8, symfony/finder:v4.4.8, ralouphie/getallheaders:3.0.3, psr/http-message:1.0.1, guzzlehttp/psr7:1.6.1, guzzlehttp/promises:v1.3.1, symfony/polyfill-php72:v1.17.0, symfony/polyfill-intl-idn:v1.17.0, guzzlehttp/guzzle:6.5.3, symfony/process:v4.4.8, facebook/webdriver:1.7.1, codeception/codeception:2.4.0
[374.8MiB/173.28s]   - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (3.0.0): [374.9MiB/173.28s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/173.28s]
[374.9MiB/173.28s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/173.51s]   - Installing sebastian/exporter (3.1.2): [374.9MiB/173.52s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/173.52s]
[374.9MiB/173.52s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/173.75s]   - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.3.0): [374.9MiB/173.76s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/173.76s]
[374.9MiB/173.76s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/174.00s]   - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): [374.9MiB/174.00s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/174.00s]
[374.9MiB/174.00s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/174.23s]   - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (6.1.2): [374.9MiB/174.23s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/174.23s]
[374.9MiB/174.23s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/174.55s]   - Installing codeception/stub (1.0.4): [374.9MiB/174.56s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/174.56s]
[374.9MiB/174.56s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/174.80s]   - Installing sebastian/diff (3.0.2): [374.9MiB/174.80s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/174.80s]
[374.9MiB/174.80s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/175.07s]   - Installing sebastian/comparator (3.0.2): [374.9MiB/175.07s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/175.07s]
[374.9MiB/175.07s]  Extracting archive[374.9MiB/175.33s]   - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.1.3): [374.9MiB/175.33s] Loading from cache[374.9MiB/175.33s]
```

The run before

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for codeception/codeception 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.4.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/finder v5.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/finder v5.0.8
    - codeception/codeception 2.4.0 requires symfony/finder >=2.7 <5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.50, v2.7.51, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.52, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.4, v3.4.40, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/finder[v2.7.0, v5.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/finder[v2.7.1, v5.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/finder[v2.7.10, v5.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/finder[v2.7.11, v5.0.8].
```

**2)  YES** Btw, prestissimo as I mentioned was already applied and it seemed to help, as on another very fast computer which has much faster internet altogether without codeception, installation took 5 times more, 518 seconds, while perhaps due to prestissimo or other advices here, it took 110 seconds.

`composer global require hirak/prestissimo`

**3)  YES** Windows is slow, and so are virtualized folders from Windows to Linux.
Running outside the shared folder inside Linux seemed to speed it up about twice.
Though it could be due cache.

**4) NO**

```
    "process-timeout": 1800,
```

is per single process like git checkout and did not seem to help at all even set to 10s, as it was already considerably huge. It perhaps helps only when there is a total outage of some service.

**5)  YES** installing with a vendor folder removed or empty=freshly seems to be considerably faster (about 1 minute and more), than adding to the vendor files and other packages existing in it

**6)  YES** seems to be slower on Ubuntu18 apache2 without xdebug own image, than on Debian10 php-fpm even with xdebug at Yii2-starter-kit , for some reason about twice slower , `cat /etc/*-release` to find out the Linux distribution

**7) NO**
`php -ddefault_socket_timeout=1  /usr/local/bin/composer  --verbose --profile install` mentioned in here did not seem to help
[Slow updating of composer dependencies, despite --prefer-dist flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316650/slow-updating-of-composer-dependencies-despite-prefer-dist-flag#comment66520697_34594930)
nor there mentioned IP v6 v v4 protocol
Though it could be due cache.

**8) NO** Installing zip doesn't seem to help, PHP installation had zip preinstalled, it still complained not being there until were installed as Linux packages but it made process in a single simulation slower by 100 seconds from 650 to 750 seconds. Same environmental conditions.
`As there is no 'unzip' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51208804/3419535
testing on cacheless conditions `--no-cache`

**9) YES** remove   `"minimum-stability ": "dev",`

**10) YES** use prefer-dist `composer require robmorgan/phinx:@dev --prefer-dist -vvv --profile`  (using a require command as an example, as using partial require commands as mentioned very first above, instead of a full installation via an install command, seems to be one of the most significant speedups, plus requiring @dev- as along the previous points when `minimum-stability: dev` not applied generically to all dependencies seems to be harmless using on per case(dependency) basis)

Comment: How is this related to the given question? Accoirding to the problem description, there is not a single dependency listed in the OPs problem

Comment: The problem should be addressed generically, I tried to summarize all that helped me, and added some other solutions from elsewhere.Not always only for what the asker asks for, here come thousands of other users scenarios.Majority of responses are generic. Composer require is basically just a subpart of composer install. Just because I used also a word/command 'require' in the response, does not mean it does not apply also to install,but if you wish I can remove that word.'There is not a single dependency listed', but how it changes anything, composer install is about nothing but dependencies.

Comment: I went from 1 point to -1 just a few mins after because I replied to you, maybe because you voted me up previously.  Tell me that the chosen answer prestistimo or using ipv 6 or disabling xdebug is not generic too and do not apply to a concrete composer require command. I apologize for a few haste edits but I use it also as a personal wiki, and I did not even list a concrete depedency name, but will adjust it. If you dont like I did a typo, mention that, but not being generic doesnt make sense. I used a 'require' command as a reference, as using 'require' is one of the solutions itself.

Comment: The OP asked why Composer is slow **with zero dependencies** - even if your list of stuff might help in many other situations, I see no connection to the given question

Comment: You are correct regards that but I either overlooked that or wondered if the user did not use it just for the mere exaggeration of the topic to distance from anybody thinking a particular dependency could be the cause. Somehow when solving it I stumble upon this question from google all the time, maybe also because it is the most popular/most answers regards this topic. And also because the headlines is very generic `Why is php composer so slow`.

Comment: You know like sometimes is important also how the community forms the question, the guy can be a one-question guy. You say we should focus on the details what the OP asks,though many moderators explicitly require to be generic. But you say he wanted an empty dependency list,I wonder how the chosen answer with 400 votes using prestissimo paralel downloading benefits an empty dependency list. Or the question with 100 votes. Same with other answers ips,timeouts.It might be not the most proper way, but that's how huge stackoverflow behaves with popular questions.I read between lines of prestisimo.

Comment: Well, the OP has selected an answer (XDebug should not be enabled) and wrote that the problem was solved after having disabled XDebug

Comment: You are right, however that reply is becoming outdated, my comment about that got thrice upvoted. Plus ten time more 365 -  people/developers voted for the prestissimo reply, which is unrelated to en empty list. Just saying, the community subconsciously or not want this question to evolve into/answer a different(generic) question, of the composer being slow generally then imo. He asked for an empty list, but in practice solving an issue of an empty list on daily basis is just ludicrous if not used mainly for description. So this question should not have become that popular but other.

Comment: Prestissimo helps even with empty require list - some files are downloaded by composer regardless of dependencies list, so parallel download will help here too.

Comment: If it's the case - seems reasonable, then beg my pardon, though I am still not sure the reply is voted for an empty list, and you can delete these my comments if you want. Thanks

Comment: This answer helped me, I had this problem for almost three days, you just have to increase the composer timeout, that's it

Answer (score 2):

I found another possible solution , **the problem is lack of `cUrl` extension in your environment**.So please follow these steps

1. Firstly , check if you have accesss to

   ***packagist.org*** with *`ping packagist.org`*.If you got reply back from the server , you are ready for the next step.
2. Check if cUrl extension exists with `composer diagnose` , for me I got these results which says I don't have `cUrl` extension ,so it may reduce performance during downloading things
   [image]
3. install curl according to your environment's php version ,mine was 8 ,so `sudo apt-get install php8.0-curl` worked for me
4. after installing cUrl , please check if it was installed with again `composer diagnose`, and I got these results,which describes cUrl version.
   [image]
5. That solved my problem with composer slowing down when installing packages.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the composer version i was running backdated.
After updated the composer version itself the problem was gone.

To update the composer version run

```
composer self-update
```

and then require the composer package and you're done.

```
composer require "<package-name>"
```

Comment: sudo ? root ? why ?

Comment: sorry brother, add sudo if you've permission issues.

Comment: or should you fix file mode and owner/group permissions? rather than just running SUDO! without knowing what that means? definitely not a FIX.

Comment: of course, you can fix the owner/group permission issue by running the "chown" command, but you can do this in one go. My main intension was to show the solution in the simplest way from my point of view. However, I'm sorry if my words don't make any sense to you.

Comment: @sh6210 Do not encourage to use sudo when using composer. Assuming there 'might' a `permission` problem is prejudice.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the previous answers don't work, check if your firewall allows for TCP_OUT on port 9418.

My firewall security was too sharp. This caused Composer to take so long, I never got any timeout or indication the port was blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was slow when downloading json files because of the antivirus. Some antiviruses scan all web traffic and it may be slow at analyzing json files. Try disabling your AV while running composer.

Answer (score 0):

step 1

```
$ composer self-update
```

step 2

```
$ composer clear-cache
```

step 3

```
$ composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 PHPStorm windows open on 2 different projects, the first project ran fast and the second was slow for composer install and for composer start, I left it on all day to do install. A powershell window had the same issue. When I closed the first project composer start ran well in the second project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is right about disabling XDebug, but doesn't elaborate on how to do so. For anyone like me who came here trying to speed up the `composer install` on their GitHub Actions CI/CD workflows, disabling `xdebug` and similar debugging tools while setting up PHP can result in a significant decrease in build time and usage.

GitHub's documentation for the Ubuntu 22.04 Github Actions runner states that [Xdebug is enabled by default](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#php-tools), and the [documentation of Shivam Mathur's Setup PHP action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-php-action#xdebug) also makes mention of this:

> Note: Xdebug is enabled by default on Ubuntu GitHub Actions images, so if you are not using it in your workflow it is recommended to disable it as that will have a positive impact on your PHP performance. Please refer to the disable coverage section for details.

It recommends disabling it by adding `coverage: none` to your GitHub Actions workflows:

```
- name: Setup PHP
  uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
    with:
    php-version: 8.1
    coverage: none        # Add this
    extensions: :xdebug   # OR add this to only disable XDebug - note the colon
- name: Run Composer install
  run: composer install -o -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
```

However, bear in mind that if you make use of GitHub Actions' advanced [debug logging](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) or plan to in the future, XDebug at least will probably need to be re-enabled for it.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to find out is running composer update/install with verbosity. composer {install/update} -vvv. Using the flag -h may help you in the future

Comment: Please share an explanation for that. The OP is running the tests using a completely empty list of dependencies

Answer (score -1):

In case, If you have deleted your composer.lock file, and then gone for `composer install` it gets too slow to download dependencies.
If this is the case, use `composer update` command and then it may help you or others.